# Removing HTML code from a javaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, href

Hi I have the following code in a javaScript file called songs:

```
var marchMD = new Array();
marchMD[0] = ["Save the Best for Last - Vanessa Williams"];
marchMD[1] = ["Informer - Snow"];
marchMD[2] = ["The Sign - Ace of Base"];    

for (var i=0;i<marchMD.length; i++) {
    songList = songList + '<p><a href="#" id="songtext">' + marchMD[i] + '</a></p>';
}
$('#songs').html(songList);
```

Once this has been loaded, the follow javaScript in the file youtube reacts with the code above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#songs p').click(function(e) {

        var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
        var search = $el.html();
        //alert(search);
        //return;

        var keyword = encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + keyword + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc';

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: yt_url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.data.items) {
                    $.each(response.data.items, function(i, data) {
                        var video_id = data.id;
                        var video_frame = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id + "' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";
                        $("#ytVid").html(video_frame);
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#ytVid").hmtl("<div id='no'> No Video</div>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The alert that I have in the code above was a test to see if it would return anything and it doesn't. However, if I remove the href html tag from the code this works. The reason I have it is so when someone clicks one of the songs, it takes them to the top of the page to view that song in youtube.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have an array of arrays of strings, instead of just `marchMD = ["blah", "blah2", "blah3"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the element that contains your link will only ever contain your link, you could use `text()` to strip out the HTML formatting, like this:

```
 var search = $el.text();
```

Comment: It's not necessarily the element that was clicked, it's the element that you bound the event on, the click event may have bubbled up. For the element that was clicked you should use http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: I did this and I get "<a href="#" id="songtext">Save the Best for Last - Vanessa Williams</a>" returned. The <a href="#" id="songtext"> and </a> are messing up my youtube searches.

Comment: The .text() was all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: The answer has a lot of noise, I recommend you remove your comments about `$.html` and `this` since they have nothing to do with the solution the OP was looking for.

Comment: @JuanMendes: Edited it to be *much* more concise. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the `<a>` in there, `var search = $el.html();` includes the tag as well, not just the text. Try this:

```
   $('#songs p').click(function(e) {
        var search = $(this).find('a').html();
```